# Initialize string type elements in a struct

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to dynamically store the contents of a pointer into a struct. I defined the struct as follows:

```
struct msg3 {
    uint16_t     msgSize;  // 2 bytes
    uint16_t     msgType;  // 2 bytes
    uint32_t     symbolIndex;  // 4 bytes
};
```

I then proceed to initialize a struct of type msg3 using code below.
(Packet is of type const u_char*).

```
const msg3* msg3_ = reinterpret_cast<const msg3*>(packet);
```

The above works fine, and sizeof(msg3) accurately returns 8.

Following the first 8 bytes in packet, there is 11 bytes of null-terminated ASCII characters.

I try to add a string as an element of the struct to capture the following 11 bytes of ASCII characters that are null-terminated:

```
struct msg3 {
    uint16_t     msgSize;  // 2 bytes
    uint16_t     msgType;  // 2 bytes
    uint32_t     symbolIndex;  // 4 bytes
    std::string  symbol;     // 11 bytes
};
```

Under this definition of struct (with the additional symbol element), sizeof(msg3) returns 32 when I want it to return 19. Plus, when I try to access msg3_.symbol, I get a segmentation fault.  Why is this happening?

Essentially, I am trying to replicate

```
std::string symbol = (char*)packet + 8;
```

within the definition of the struct.

Comment: If the sum of the size of an object contents is x, then this doesn't guarantee that object has the same size as the sum. read about structure padding

Comment: @asmmo Thanks for the comment on structure padding. More accurately, I am curios how I can setup the struct such that std::string symbol reads the 11 bytes after the first 8. Essentially, I am trying to do something like `std::string symbol = (char*)packet + 8; ` but within the definition of the struct.

Comment: "_I then proceed to initialize a struct of type msg3 using code below. (Packet is of type const u_char*)_" - no you don't.

Comment: @VimellPresadYuvarajah If it's always 11 bytes, add a `char symbol[11];` at the end of the struct. Otherwise if it's not a fixed size packet, then you won't be able to do it (cleanly) with a direct cast, since any struct must have a fixed size known at compile time.

Comment: *I try to add a string as an element of the struct to capture the following 11 bytes of ASCII characters that are null-terminated:* -- The `std::string` is not a POD type.  Use a regular char array.

Comment: If I understand correctly, why not create a *wrapper* struct, e.g. `struct wrapper { struct msg; char symbol[11]; };` which would allow you to initialize the `msg` member as you do now, and then fill the `symbol` and reference both though the wrapper? Otherwise you are changing the size of the `msg` struct and your current assignment/initialization won't be the same. (add `+1` to `symbol` if `11` doesn't include the *nul-terminating* character)

Comment: @dxiv Got it. That helped. Thank you. Basically replace std::string symbol with char symbol[11].